# Аналитика данных мобильного приложения ios

Tags: ios

Всем привет!
Нужен совет по мобильной аналитике и ее сервисам. Ситуация следующая: Релизнули приложение, после релиза стали настраивать аналитику и события. Для валидации подписок я выбрала apphud (аналог revenuecat), для отслеживания траффика и рекл. кампаний appsflyer, продуктовую аналитику завели в fb analytics. Есть так же appmetrica и аналитика из applestore connect. 
Вопрос:
Одни и те же показатели по ивентам во всех сервисах очень различаются (например установки за день) из applestore connect, fb analytics, appsflyer. Flyer и connect отличаются в 2 раза! Почему так происходит, нормально ли это и кому верить? как правильно протестировать работу событий? Ивенты по валидации только вчера выкатили и по ним пока не могу сравнить данные. Поделитесь пожалуйста, как вы настраивали валидацию и как правильно отслеживать данные по подпискам?

Comment: Вы не можете быть уверенными, что тот или иной сервис по аналитике покажит вам все данные сразу же как они есть, связи с тем, что все это дело обновляется у всех сервисов по разному или в какой-то определенный период, они все будут давать разную информацию. Взять даже метрику, она может неделями обновлять статистику и показать в итоге вообще другую статистику, за определенный период, а не на текущий момент. Там все из-за частоты обновлений статистики зависит и от многих других факторов.

Comment: как тогда понимать общую картину происходящего?